# No HTTP resource was found

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

I added this on my api department conrtoller however when I run it the website says that it is not found, I am not familiar with c# any help with do..

```
  [HttpDelete]
            [AcceptVerbs("Delete")]
            [ResponseType(typeof(Department))]
            public override async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(Department tObj, bool? tagAsDeleteOnly)
            {
                _bll.Delete(tObj, tagAsDeleteOnly ?? true);

                var result = await _bll.Save();

                return Ok(new WebResult
                {
                    Data = tObj,
                    Total = (int)result,
                    Result = result > 0
                });
            }
```

the error says

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8933/api/Department/Delete'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Department' that matches the request."
}
```

this is what I am passing 
[what i pass picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RFAe.png)

this is my code on my front end

```
delete(form) {
        debugger
        form.State = 2;
        let id = form.Key;
        //delete form.Key;
        this.props.deleter('department/Delete', form);
}
```

and then it proceed to

```
export const deleter = (url, params) => {
    return(dispatch, getState, api) => {
        api += 'api/';
        return fetch(`${api}${url}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => dispatch(departmentResult(result, types.DELETER)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you definitely sending a Delete request as specified by the [HttpDelete] attribute?

Comment: How do you pass `Department` object?

Comment: i am not sure what you meant was but.. im sending the item unto `api/Department/Delete'` @AlanBuchanan

Comment: @LAGIM, you have parameter `Department tObj`, in url there is no such parameter and `DELETE` request doesn't have body, so you don't have matching action

Comment: @RomaDoskoch   `public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] T tObj)` (this is inside the baseAPI)... on the website i use `/api/department/post`

Comment: An HTTP request has a method e.g. GET or POST - you've specified that your action only accepts a DELETE method by using the [HttpDelete] attribute. How are you generating the request e.g. web form, AJAX etc. ?

Comment: @RomaDoskoch i just use my supervisor sample of code for delete, i usually use the one that has (int key).. I used that because i also pass the form in react when I add or edit stuffs `this.props.post('department/post', form);`

Comment: I ajax it on react by using `return fetch(`${api}${url}`, {
   method: 'DELETE',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(params)` @AlanBuchanan

Comment: @LAGIM, but `DELETE` request can't have body.

Comment: @RomaDoskoch then how should I do it?

Comment: @LAGIM, you should pass all parameters in your url. Also, why do you need to pass whole object? If you want to delete some entity you can pass some `Id` (or another property which identifies element which should be deleted) and delete entity using this passed parameter.

Comment: @RomaDoskoch I am passing the whole parameter i think, check out i edited my question ...

Comment: @LAGIM, you pass parameters in `body` - `body: JSON.stringify(params)`, but `DELETE` request can't have body - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE

Answer (score 1):

Whilst a body is not explicitly forbidden in a `DELETE` request, it is frequently ignored by the server.

Try changing your Action to

```
public override async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(string departmentCode, bool? tagAsDeleteOnly)
```

and construct your url using parameters ie add `?departmentCode=params.Code`

Also worth checking [this post](http://www.spenceruresk.com/2011/11/http-delete-requests-that-include-a-body/) found an error where the library performing the request automatically turned a `DELETE` into a `POST` if there was a message body present.

You can easily verify this by using the Developer Tools in your browser (or changing the attribute to `[AcceptVerbs("Post")]` at least for testing